# How to get only file name without extension in GNU Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have taken this answer from other post. Following prints file name with extension. This works only for cpp files, not for the header files when retrieved this pre processor value `FILE_NAME` inside C code.

```
-D FILE_NAME=\"$(<F)\"
```

How to get only source file name without extension?

Comment: What is the relation to C++? You only mention C code! What is the relation to GNU makefiles? BTW: You might be able to use the predefined `__FILE__` macro.

Comment: What is the actual use case? Why do you ask? Please **edit your question** to improve it!

Comment: I want to log only file name in my C/C++ program. Want to do that during pre processing time. So added a macro in Makefile. __FILE__  give full path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The predefined function [`basename`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) removes the suffix (extension) from a filename, so if `$(<F)` is the filename you are interested in then `$(basename $(<F))` is the name without the extension:

```
-D FILE_NAME=\"$(basename $(<F))\"
```

Comment: basename filename gives filename with extension for me. It removes only the directory path.

Comment: That's what the command [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html) does, but that's not the same as GNU Make's `$(basename ...)` function. Did you actually try it in the makefile?

Comment: My bad. its working. Was struggling with the syntax. Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: @JonathanWakely why is it in doublequotes? It does not have to be

Comment: @Herdsman ask OP, not me. I just adapted what they had, to answer the question.

Comment: @JonathanWakely maybe bad question but I still do not know the full meaning of 'OP', I know you reference the one that have written the question, but what is literal translation of 'OP'? (do not laugh please)

Answer (score 0):

I tend to believe that there is no C++11 standard way (but you might have [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) specific ways) to do that. Of course you could use `__FILE__` [predefined standard macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html).

You might adopt a convention of having your header file `foo.h` (with an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)) doing

```
 #ifndef FOO_INCLUDED
 #define FOO_INCLUDED
 #define MY_HEADER_BASE_NAME FOO
 /// rest of header goes here
 #undef MY_HEADER_BASE_NAME
 #undef /* FOO_INCLUDED*/
```

Then use `MY_HEADER_BASE_NAME`... BTW, the above schema won't work well with nested headers.